# Como faço um sistema de traduções no PHP e manter a tradução ao trocar páginas?

Tags: php

Bem, estou necessitado de um sistema de traduções via PHP, porém, desejo que ao ser traduzido o link fique parecido com esse: [www.meudominio.com.br/en ou www.meudominio.com.br/pt](http://www.meudominio.com/en) ao mesmo tempo que ele vai deixar salvo o tipo de linguagem, quero que dê pra entrar em outras páginas, ficando mais ou menos assim: [www.meudominio.com.br/en/register ou www.meudominio.com.br/pt/registro](http://www.meudominio.com/en/register) em relação a tradução do link, isso eu sei fazer, mas desejo esse estilo de sistema, se você souber como posso fazer me ajude. Já pesquisei na net, porém só encontro sistemas antigos que não funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem várias formas de se fazer tradução, uma delas é utilizando banco de dados e referenciando a palavra para cada um dos idiomas.

A outra forma seria guardar em um arquivo de texto.

Qual delas eu devo usar? Depende do seu projeto, veja o Wordpress, não usa o banco para traduzir seu sistema.

Dentro da sua pergunta existem 2 problemas, não 1 só, tente destrinchar o máximo possível.

1. traduzir
2. Roteamento.

Eu sugiro que você pesquise mais sobre roteamento e tente aprender o máximo que puder, a mudança de idioma é questão de parâmetro de rota, ao identificar o parâmetro daquela requisição, você passa a tradução que lhe apraz.

Comment: Bem, obrigado pelo comentário. Mas, já achei um jeito bom de fazer a tradução e o roteamento ao mesmo tempo. Realizei com uma função, ficando o retorno da array assim: return ((!$langueSelect[$langueVisist]) ? $langueSelect['en'][$scopoTranslate] : $langueSelect[$langueVisist][$scopoTranslate]);
Ou seja, ao mesmo tempo que ele pega seu país de origem, vai pesquisar na função se existe tradução, senão existe, ele define o idioma 'EN' como o principal do website, claro a estrutura do site, tô fazendo uma tradução de cada vez, já em relação a textos, irei por um com AJAX puxando do seu idioma.

Comment: Ai se você me perguntar como faço pro 'LangueVisist' pegar o idioma do visitante, eu utilizo: 'substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0,2)', ai minha função ficou: <?php echo $Langue->scopeLangue(BASELANGUE, 'login-connect'); ?>, rs :D